# How to find what sources are not using ssl?

Tags: php, ssl

Some folder of my website uses ssl(extended validation). In chrome when i open that folder first it works and if I leave that page(ex. home page) and go back to original folder browser shows error...

> your connection to xyx.com is secure. However some sources on this page are not secure.

Both home page and folder content share css and javascript but links are secured what can be the problem.

In firefox i dont have this problem.

edit....

If i go directly to https://www.xyz.com/xyz  it works!

if i go to http://www.xyz.com then https://www.xyz.com/xyz it shows error

if i go to https://www.xyz.com/xyz it work then if i go to http://www.xyz.com and https://www.xyz.com/xyz it shows error.

Comment: Are you displaying images that are not served via https?

Comment: image tags are like this <img src="/images/icon2.jpg" class="header-icon">

Comment: Is everything under Network tab use `https` that should? Have you restarted your browser?

Comment: alex: everything uses https and restart wont fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check links in CSS files (like background: url('...')), an http absolute link there could lead to the error you have.

Comment: I have checked that as well still same issue. Its only in chrome. Checked on multiple machines same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you press F12 in Chrome it will show you the developer tools which you can use to see all the network requests made. This might show a request done over http somewhere. 
If there aren't any http requests in there you should check all hostnames, to see if they match the name on the servers certificate. The most common error is having a request for https://example.com/... where it should have been for https://www.example.com/...

Once you've find the offending request it's probably quite clear what is causing the warning.